# Excel formula to sum an array of items from a lookup list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make my monthly transaction spreadsheet less work-intensive but I'm running up against problems outputting my category lookups as an array. Right now I have a table with all my monthly transactions and I want to create another table with monthly running totals. What I've been doing is manually summing each entry from each category, but I'd love to automate the process. Here's what I have:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Transactions[Out], N(IF(1,MATCH(I12,Transactions[Category],FALSE)))))
```

I've also tried using `AGGREGATE` in place of `SUM` but it still only returns the first value in the category. The `N(IF())` was supposed to force `INDEX` to return all the matches as an array, but it's not working. I found that trick online, with no explanation of why it works, so I really don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Some sample data and the expected output, or a sample screenshot, would be helpful here.

Comment: `MATCH` will only return a single number, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone ever looks at this thread in the future, I was able to find a simpler solution to my problem once I implemented the `Transactions[Category]=I12` method. `SUM`, itself will take an array as an argument, so all I had to do was form an array of the values I wanted to keep from `Transactions[Out]` range. I did this by adjusting the method Ron described above, but instead of using `1/(Transactions[Category]=I12` I used `1/IF(Transactions[Category]=I12, 1,1000)` and surrounded that by a `FLOOR(*resulting array*, .01)` which rounded all the thousandth's down to zero and didn't yield any `#DIV/0!` errors.

Then! I realized that the simplest way to get the actual numbers I wanted, rather than messing with `INDEX` or `AGGREGATE`, was to multiply the range `Transactions[Out]` by the binary array from the `IF` test. Since the range is a table, I know they will always be the same size. And `SUM` automatically multiplies element by element and then adds for operations like this.

(The result is a "CSE" formula, which I guess isn't everyone's favorite. I'm still not 100% clear on what it means: just that it outputs data in a single cell, rather than over multiple cells. But in this context, `SUM` should only output a single number, so I'm not sure why I need CSE... A problem for another day!)

Answer (score 0):

In your `IF`, the `value_if_true` clause needs to return an array of the desired row numbers from the array.

`MATCH` does not return an array of values; it only returns a single value which, with the `FALSE` parameter, will be the first value.  That's why `INDEX` is only returning the first value.

One way to return an array of values:

```
Transactions[Category]=I12
```

will return an array of `{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,...}` depending on if it matches.

You can then multiply that by the Row number to get the relevant row on the worksheet.

Since you are using a table, to obtain the row number in the data body array, you have to subtract the row number of the Header row.

But now we are going to have an array which includes `0`'s for the non-matching entries, which is not good for us as a row number argument for the `INDEX` function.

So we get rid of that by using the `AGGREGATE` function with the `ignore errors` argument set after we do change the equality test to `1/(Transactions[Category]=I12)` which will create `DIV/0` errors for the non-matchers.

Putting it all together

```
=SUM(INDEX(Transactions[Out],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(Transactions[Category]=I12)*ROW(Transactions)-ROW(Transactions[#Headers]),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF(Transactions[Category],$I$12))))))
```

You may need to enter this with CSE depending on your version of Excel.

Also, if you have a lot of these formulas, you may want to change the `k` argument for `AGGREGATE` to use the `INDEX` function (non-volatile) instead of the volatile `INDIRECT` function.

```
    =SUM(INDEX(Transactions[Out],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(Transactions[Category]=I12)*ROW(Transactions)-ROW(Transactions[#Headers]),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF(Transactions[Category],$I$12),1)))))
```

**Edit**

If you have Excel/O365 with dynamic arrays and the `FILTER` function, you can greatly simplify the above to the normally entered:

```
=SUM(FILTER(Transactions[Out],Transactions[Category]=I12))
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this is very thorough! I'm at work so I don't have time to really dig into it at the moment, but I will this evening. In my googling before, someone had recommended using the ```AGGREGATE``` function. I'm new to this level of Excel programming - very out of my depth for now.

Comment: @KevinA. You will get there.

Comment: @KevinA.  If you have Excel for Office 365 with all the updates, see my **Edit** for a simpler formula.